# Browse a list of dict in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I need to browse a list of python dictionary my list is as follows

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "warranty",
  "doc" : "Schema generated by Kite",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '1'"
  }, {
    "name" : "train_id",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '21691'"
  }, {
    "name" : "siemens_nr",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Loco-001'"
  }, {
    "name" : "uic_nr",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '193901'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Configuration",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'ZP28'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Warranty_Status",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Out_of_Warranty'"
  }]
```

How can I get only the name and type of the fields entity thanks (ps: it's a JSON file)

i wrote this code :

```
   with open('/data/my-data/archive/in/test_warranty_data.csv.txt.avro.txt', 'r') as f:   
    i=0
    data = json.load(f)
    for ele in data["fields"]:
      print ele.[i].["name"]
      print ele.[i].["type"]
      i++
```

May be you can suggest me something more efficient :) thank you

Comment: Please read [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add code you your question, highlighting what the the problems that you cannot find. StackOverflow is not a "someone-writes-my-code-for-free" service

Comment: there are a couple of mistakes there as well

Comment: I wrote more details :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ele.[i].["name"]` is not legal Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume you have the below json file called data.json:

```
{
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '1'"
  }, {
    "name" : "train_id",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '21691'"
  }, {
    "name" : "siemens_nr",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Loco-001'"
  }, {
    "name" : "uic_nr",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '193901'"
  }]
}
```

And below code can help to extract the name and type:

```
import json

f = open("data.json", "r")
data = json.load(f)
fields = data["fields"]
for field in fields:
    print(field['name'])
    print(field['type'])
    print("==================")
```

output is :

```
id
long
==================
train_id
long
==================
siemens_nr
string
==================
uic_nr
long
==================
```

Comment: Thank you :) i used your solution